# Default server for mvn tomcat:deploy?

Tags: tomcat, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm trying to deploy a war with  `mvn tomcat:deploy` and I get

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project navigator-native: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: ...//localhost:8080/manager/deploy? ...

I've already added the roles to tomcat-users.xml :

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin,manager"/>
```

But don't want to modify the project's POM.xml, so what is the default server used for the plugin? I've tried adding

```
<server>
    <id>localhost</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>password</password>
</server>
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Default url is `http://localhost:8080/manager` per [tomcat 6 maven plugin docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/tomcat6-maven-plugin/deploy-only-mojo.html).  Not sure if it's the same for tomcat 7.

Comment: but the server Id is the same as the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default url is `http://localhost:8080/manager` per [Tomcat 6 maven plugin docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/tomcat6-maven-plugin/deploy-only-mojo.html). Not sure if it's the same for tomcat 7.

For manager credentials, you add a server block to the `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` file.  Then you need to define the server ID by specifying the `<server>` element in the Tomcat plugin config, or on the command line:

`mvn tomcat:deploy -Dmaven.tomcat.server=localhost <otherPropertiesHere>`

The above assumes the server ID is "localhost" as shown in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The id you're referring is the one in the plugin configuration, not the actual server, if you don't want to modify the pom's project either create a profile in the settings.xml file or pass the configuration in the command line:

`mvn tomcat:deploy -Dmaven.tomcat.url=http://localhost/manager`, also get sure you set -`Dmaven.tomcat.update=true` if you redeploy